Actuator health url requires authentication
My spring project has actuator implemented. It is deployed on GCP. While deploying it on localhost, the /actuator/health url works from the browser without any authentication. But while hitting the apigee url after deployment on GCP, it throws forbidden error. It works from Postman when hit with the authentication header.
Following is the configuration in application.yml:
management:
    endpoint:
        health:
            enabled: true
            probes:
                enabled: false
    health:
        redis:
            enabled: false
    endpoints:
        web:
            exposure:
                include: health,info,refresh

I want the health url to be accessible without authentication. What could be the issue here?

It is impossible to guess what the issue is without knowing how the Apigee proxy is configured. Could you perhaps share what policies are configured on the proxy?

Where should I check for these policies?

On Apigee edge UI.
